# Create NA's based on another dataframe without long data

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a `tibble` with the explicit "id" and colnames I need to convert to NA's. Is there anyway I can create the NA's without making my `df` a long dataset? I considered using the new `rows_update` function, but I'm not sure if this is correct because I only want certain columns to be NA.

```r
library(dplyr)

to_na <- tribble(~x, ~col,
        1, "z",
        3, "y"
)

df <- tibble(x = c(1,2,3), 
       y = c(1,1,1), 
       z = c(2,2,2)) 

# desired output:
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>       x     y     z
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1    NA
#> 2     2     1     2
#> 3     3    NA     2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `row/column` indexing to assign the values to `NA` in `base R`

```
df <- as.data.frame(df)
df[cbind(to_na$x, match(to_na$col, names(df)))] <- NA
df
#  x  y  z
#1 1  1 NA
#2 2  1  2
#3 3 NA  2
```

---

If we want to use `rows_update`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
lst1 <- to_na %>%
            mutate(new = NA_real_) %>%
            split(seq_len(nrow(.))) %>%
            map(~ .x %>% 
               pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = new))
for(i in seq_along(lst1)) df <- rows_update(df, lst1[[i]])

df
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#       x     y     z
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1    NA
#2     2     1     2
#3     3    NA     2
```

Comment: This is pretty close to what I'm looking for but not exactly 1, y and 3, z should keep their values

Comment: new edit is correct, do you know if there is a straight-forward dplyr way? If no, I'll take your word.

Comment: @John-Henry I updated the post.  If you are looking for rows_update, it requires a specific format to get updated

Answer (score 1):

This definitely isn't the most elegant solution, but it gets the output you want.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

to_na <- tribble(~x, ~col,
                 1, "z",
                 3, "y"
)

df <- tibble(x = c(1,2,3), 
             y = c(1,1,1), 
             z = c(2,2,2))

map2(to_na$x, to_na$col, #Pass through these two objects in parallel
     function(xval_to_missing, col) df %>% #Two objects above matched by position here.
                          mutate_at(col, #mutate_at the specified cols
                                    ~if_else(x == xval_to_missing, NA_real_, .) #if x == xval_to_missing, make NA, else keep as is.
                                    ) %>% 
                          select(x, col) #keep x and the modified column.
     ) %>% #end of map2
reduce(left_join, by = "x") %>% #merge within the above list, by x.
relocate(x, y, z) #Keep your ordering
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
      x     y     z
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1    NA
2     2     1     2
3     3    NA     2
```